# Micro services for graphql

Tags: ajax, microservices, graphql

I have created a graphql server that send data to client and show results to react component using relay. If i want't to get data from different sources( different server or different DB) I have to change my resolve function and put there the code that get data with ajax for example?

Answer (score 0):

Correct.
All you need to do is to resolve to the right source,
You can either return a value or a promise for a value.